# How do I can call a jar file from wso2

Tags: jar, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am new to esb WSO2 and I need to call a .jar with WSO2 parameters. I think I need to create a endpoint and call the jar file. Is it right?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Calling a JAR file? What you are going to do with that?

Comment: Probably the question wasn't set correctly. As far as I understand you're looking to invoke some custom mediation logic that is implemented in Java?

Comment: I need to call a JAR file because I need to communicate with another system that has no API or other system integration.

Comment: could you please elaborate the requirement further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using the [Script Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator) (Groovy language). So from within the Groovy script I called my custom method by passing it the payload as JSON and saved the return value of that method as the payload. I used JSON for the payload, but feel free to leave it to default XML. You can also pass parameters, not just the payload, to your custom method.

```
<script language="groovy">
    println "---------- start java call -----------"
    mc.setPayloadJSON(new my.own.package.MyClass().myMethod(mc.getPayloadJSON()))
    println "----------- end java call ----------"
</script>
```

Added my custom jar, JSON and Groovy jars under *{ESB_ROOT}/repository/components/lib* and bounced the WSO2 ESB.

There are probably other ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: in my Method, how to type is the input variable?
How I active groovy script?

Comment: @davidad: The parameter for the method is a `NativeObject` object, which can be imported as `org.mozilla.javascript.NativeObject`. Not sure I understand your second question. Adding the script mediator shown in the answer somewhere in your `inSequence`, `outSequence` or some other custom sequence you created should suffice.